How to suppress Gnome's file explorer notifications?
How can I suppress the following notification in Gnome's file explorer? I couldn't find the settings anywhere. It is annoying me, always covering other files I would like to click on.


I don't know how to suppress them in the first place, but if you are lucky, it should be possible to dismiss them with a quick hit of the Escape key on the keyboard, which would be easier and faster than having to intercept that small x with the mouse.

This can be achieved using two methods:
dconfig Editor
In dconf Editor navigate to org/gnome/desktop/notifications/application/org-gnome-nautilus/

Then set enable off using the slider.
If not already installed, you can install dconf Editor with the following command in terminal:
sudo apt -y install dconf-editor
Settings application
Settings > Notifications > Files

Turn off Notofications and/or Notification Popups as required.
